# Accessing oracle type attributes from system tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to access oracle type attribute information from any of the system tables? For example given a type:

```
create or replace 
type CUSTOM_TYPE as object
(
  id NUMBER,
  name VARCHAR2,
  ...    
)
```

I would like to be able to access information of the form

```
type_name,attribute_name,positon,data_type
CUSTOM_TYPE,ID,1,NUMBER
CUSTOM_TYPE,NAME,2,VARCHAR2
```

This sort of functionality is available for function and procedure arguments in the user_arguments table, but I have been unable to find anything similar for type attributes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 0):

This query will list all the type objects owned by the current user.

```
select * from user_types;
```

Check [this link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sys_tables/) for all available system tables and a brief on their contained information.